# Start two Jakarta EE (Java EE) project simultaneously using Glassfish in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have two *Jakarta EE* projects, one *REST service* (for back-end) and the other *Web application* (for front-end) and I want to use them simultaneously (client/server). When I try to start both projects I've got this error:

> Address localhost:4848 is already in use

HTTP port of *Glassfish* is 8080 and administration panel port is 4848.

How can I start both projects with two instance of *Glassfish* server?

Comment: Try deploying both applications to the same Glassfish, instead of starting two "Glassfishes" or change the port numbers of the second instance.

Comment: Thanks but this is an exhausting way. I want to debug front-end project inside IDE so I need to work them simultaneously. I can't deploy the project every time I have a minor change @ThiagoHenriqueHupner

Comment: In IDEA it is possible IIRC to have both projects opened at the same time, and it deploys both applications very fast